# Pyserial in Python(List out available comports without for loop)

Tags: python, port, python-3.5, pyserial

```
import serial.tools.list_ports

ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()

print(ports)
#[<serial.tools.list_ports_common.ListPortInfo object at 0x000001D48771C9B0>, <serial.tools.list_ports_common.ListPortInfo object at 0x000001D48866FB00>]
```

As you can see the comports are not readable, I can make it readable through for loops but I need it in list with readable word, eg. ["COM1","COM2","COM3"]

Anyone has any idea to change it? I tried create a new list and append in the loop also no luck. When I print out the result is the same.

UPDATES:
I think what I did last time was appending each object together again. I am able to get the specific information I want which is COM with the code below:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports

ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()

available_ports = []

for p in ports:
    available_ports.append(p.device)

print(available_ports)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through the list and get the names:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports

ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()

print([port.name for port in ports])
```

Comment: Thanks!! I just got no idea how to access the other information in the object, I didn't know I can access name through port.name. I think you solved my problem but I don't have equipment with me rn I can't test it.

Comment: On Windows I had to use `port.device` because `port.name` was empty.

Answer (score 2):

```
ports = [p.name for p in comports()]
```

statement prints

```
[None, None, None, None]
```

in Windows 10 (with **python 3.61** + **pyserial v3.4**). Changed to

`ports = [p.device for p in comports()]`

to get valid port name.

```
['COM1', 'COM2', 'COM5', 'COM6']
```

Answer (score 1):

The `comports()` method return `ListPortInfo` object.

Then, you can access a bunch of attributes of this class to get the desired results:

- `name`: Short device name, e.g. `ttyUSB0`
- `device`: Full device name/path, e.g. `/dev/ttyUSB0`

[See the docs](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html#serial.tools.list_ports.ListPortInfo).

An general solution for this, could be:

```
from serial.tools.list_ports import comports

ports = [p.name for p in comports()]

print(ports)
```

Comment: Thanks! I already read it few times but I don't get the idea how to access the specific information. I think I will solve my problem tomorrow when I have my equipment. Thanks @Abe

Comment: Glad to help !!

Answer (score 0):

As a slightly nasty hack, the object returned by comports() is a generator. You can get a list (in this case a list of lists, or 2D table) simply by casting:

```
from serial.tools.list_ports import comports
allPorts = list ( comports() )
print allPorts
```

However, if you just want the names, you still have to extract a column, so the above solutions are better.